# Download HTML content that require authorization?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, authorization, webclient

I use WebClient from System.Net Namespace of Visual Studio 2008 to download the HTML content.

It done well with normal website but with some 4rum that require authorization such as warez-bb.org, it always return the HTML of the login page.

I wonder if there is a way to send the username and password to the WebClient?

Answer (score 0):

See this post:
[How to fill forms and submit with Webclient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793755/how-to-fill-forms-and-submit-with-webclient-in-c)

You will likely need to use HttpWebRequest and submit form POST data manually.