# How programmatically submit a form without a submit button in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I navigated to a website with a form that has no submit button but does have form. I would like to submit this form. How to do this using C# and WebBrowser control?

Comment: you can do it with javascript? Im not sure about C# because in code behind I believe you would have to have that submit button to refer to in order to submit the form

Comment: You can do this in code without using a WebBrowser.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793755/how-to-fill-forms-and-submit-with-webclient-in-c

Comment: Did InvokeMember work for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this (or something like it):

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = this.webBrowserControl.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Form");  

foreach(HtmlElement currentElement in elements)
{
    currentElement.InvokeMember("submit");
}
```