# How to programmatically click on text input in WebBrowser using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, click, webbrowser-control

I have opened a website using WebBrowser. Now I would like to programmatically click input text (textbox) field. I can not use focus because this website uses JS to unlock this field only if it's clicked and I've tried also this:

```
Object obj = ele.DomElement;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("click");
mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

But it returns mi = null. How to do this so it will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to my answer on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539685/how-programmatically-submit-a-form-without-a-submit-button-in-webbrowser).

Get an HtmlElement respresentative of your textbox, and call HtmlElement.InvokeMember("click") on it.

Comment: I don't have InvokeMethod only InvokeMember is it this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use:

```
webbrowser1.Navigate("javascript:document.forms[0].submit()")
```

or something similar.  For me, it's been much easier and more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

To fill-up a text field on a webpage:

```
string code ="";
code = code + "var MyVar=document.getElementById('tbxFieldNameOnWebPage');if(MyVar != null) MyVar.value = 'SOMEVALUE';";
domDocument.parentWindow.execScript(code, "JScript");

Then To Click a button on a webpage:

code = "";
code = "var SignupFree = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1];";
code = (code + " SignupFree.click();");
domDocument.parentWindow.execScript(code, "JScript");
```

you can also use `document.getElementById('buttonID');` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1];` but an id must be provided for this button on that particular webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Use InvokeMethhod on HtmlElement or Browser.InvokeScript function.