# Two Questions about the WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, browser

1. How can I get an HtmlElement if the source code doesn't have the "id=''", but only has the "name=''". Document.GetElementById() doesn't work, and Document.All[""] doesn't work (obviously, because there is no ID.
2. How can I simulate a form post?

Question 1 is more important because I found it harder to search. Question 2 I think i can get with more searching.

Comment: Could you please specify what this has to do with the webbrowser control? Also, _which_ webbrowser control? WinForms? And what does this have to do with asp.net?

Comment: It's occurred to me that maybe the reason none of the solutions to item 1 is working is because you're doing it on the server side.  Is that correct?  If so, I'd strongly suggest giving the control an id.  It will save you much heartache.

Answer (score 1):

[GetElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=VS.100).aspx) could get you all of the tags that you are after, then you can look through the returned collection for the element you are after (if there is more then one).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539685/how-programmatically-submit-a-form-without-a-submit-button-in-webbrowser) post shows how to submit the form element.

Answer (score 0):

You get the element by GetElementByName also.

Comment: Actually `GetElementsByName` because the name attribute doesn't have to be unique. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Answer (score 0):

1.
You can use the `document.getElementsByName`. It returns an array with all the elements that has the specified name (as names doesn't have to be unique like id:s).

2.
You can use the `submit` method of a `form` element to post it. The form can either be an existing form in the page, or be created on the fly when you need it.

You can also use the `XmlHttpRequest` object to make a post, if you want to take care of the response yourself instead of having it load as a document.

Comment: document.getElementsById -> no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion here, so I'll summarize:

On the `document` object, there are a number of methods you can use to locate an element:

- `document.getElementById('myid');` will return a single DOM element (if it exists) with an `id` attribute equal to `myid`.
- `document.getElementsByName('myname');` will return an array of DOM elements with a `name` attribute equal to `myname`.
- `document.getElementsByTagName('div');` will return an array of DOM elements with a matching tag - in this case, all `div`s in the document.

The case is important.

Does that clear things up?

This should work with all browsers provided you're not trying to get elements inside an iframe or something like that, but if you're having trouble with different browsers, I'd suggest using something like jQuery. It abstracts the browser differences from you so you can use the same syntax regardless of the browser being used.