# how do I submit a form in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

how to programmatically set an input an element value inside a WebBrowser control?

For example, I have an HTML page, like:

```
<form method="post" action="...aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="mainForm">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit it" />
</form>
```

How do I to submit it via C# code? I tried something:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
   var doc = webBrowser1.Document;
   var input = doc.GetElementById("file");
   input.SetAttribute("value", @"C:\foo.baa");
   doc.GetElementById("mainForm").InvokeMember("submit");
}
```

but it does not working, the value of input is not setted and the form is not submited.
I hope this is clean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539685/how-programmatically-submit-a-form-without-a-submit-button-in-webbrowser

Comment: Have you registered `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` to receive `DocumentCompleted` events?

Is it actually getting to `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
HtmlElement loBtn = (HtmlElement)loWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("btnSubmit");
loBtn .InvokeMember("click");
```