# how to send Press Enter Key to htmlelement in web browser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

i'm working on win form app that contains a web browser control, in the web page there is
a text box field that i get it as htmlelement..

i fill it correctly with a string value, and then i want to send enter key press to submit
the value in it ..

this is my code so far :

```
HtmlDocument hd = wbr.Document;//wbr is web browser control
HtmlElement he = hd.GetElementById("response_field");
he.SetAttribute("value", ans);//filled correctly 
wbr.Select();
he.Focus();
he.InvokeMember("submit");
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

i tried invoke member, tried sendkey but none of them works..

how to do this?

Comment: You need to `InvokeMember("submit")` on the `<form>` element, rather than on one of its child elements. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1539685/1768303

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN - Navigated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx):

```
// Navigates to the URL in the address box when 
// the ENTER key is pressed while the ToolStripTextBox has focus.
private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```