# How to Programmatically Fill Out HTML Invoice Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have HTML template which has empty forms. How can i fill these forms from Winform?
Should i create a new class called CreateInvoiceHTML which creates invoice programmatically?

I haven't done this before, i need some quick ideas to make sure i don't go to the wrong track.

Comment: What are you going to do with the HTML pages once you add the content (email, post online, print, PDF)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mshtml_automation.aspx) should give you a head start....

Or this previously asked question should work as well.. Use the WebClient class to do the hard work... [How to fill forms and submit with Webclient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793755/how-to-fill-forms-and-submit-with-webclient-in-c)

Or you could choose from the many fine selections [here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=6nV&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=automatically+fill+out+an+html+form+C%23&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=):