# post and get request in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to make two request to submit a form of another web application. How can I create post and get request. And how can I use secure this. Please, help me.

PS. I don't want to create ajax request. Just httpwebrequest.

Comment: You can create get and post request in many ways like AJAX calls, or using dynamic Javascript... Can you be more specific?

Comment: **get** requests are just yourpageaddress.aspx?item1=value1&item2=value2, etc.

Comment: @Zenhtet: You can simply set the action method of the Html form Element to submit your request in the desired method i-e GET or POST , but in ASP.NET if you use server controls they cannot exist without aspnet server Form control and ASPnet Form control does not allow you to submit to another page.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.google.com/search?q=post+data+using+httpwebrequest&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:sv:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about requests to another server, please check out think post: [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793755/how-to-fill-forms-and-submit-with-webclient-in-c/793777#793777)

It is in C# but converting from C# to VB .Net is easy, just Google it.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.