# how to send files to another web page using web client with asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one issue for posting file content to another web page. here is my code:

```
Dim postData As String = "name=NAME2&dob=21/09/1991&add1=ADD11&add2=ADD22&city=CITY2&area=AREA2&state=STATE2&emailID=EMAILID2&Pin=380008&mobile=1234567890&IsNRI=False&stateId=1&categoryId=1&CategoryName=Test&FilePath=D:%9%SHALIN%9%HOW TO INSTALL WEBSITE TO IIS.docx"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:29478/AddressBook/Default.aspx"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"
        postReq.Referer = "http://localhost:29478/AddressBook/Default.aspx"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        postReq.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        postReq.PreAuthenticate = True
        postReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        'Dim status As Boolean = True
        'status = System.IO.File.Exists("D:\SHALIN\HOW TO INSTALL WEBSITE TO IIS.docx")
        'If status = True Then
        '    Console.WriteLine("Exists")
        'Else
        '    Console.WriteLine("Not Exists")
        'End If
        Dim wc As WebClient
        wc = New WebClient
        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2")
        'wc.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='files'; filename='HOW TO INSTALL WEBSITE TO IIS.docx'")
        wc.UploadFile(DirectCast(New Uri("http://localhost:29478/AddressBook/UploadFiles"), Uri), "PUT", "D:\SHALIN\HOW TO INSTALL WEBSITE TO IIS.docx")
        wc.Dispose()
        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
```

and at page receiver i have this code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            pnlGrid.Visible = true;
            pnlEntry.Visible = false;
            pnlReport.Visible = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        string name = null, dob = null, add1 = null, add2 = null, city = null, area = null, state = null, emailID = null, Pin = null, Mobile = null, IsNRI = null, stateId = null, categoryId = null, categoryname = null, FilePath = null;
        name = Request.Form["name"];
        dob = Request.Form["dob"];
        add1 = Request.Form["add1"];
        add2 = Request.Form["add2"];
        city = Request.Form["city"];
        area = Request.Form["area"];
        state = Request.Form["state"];
        emailID = Request.Form["emailID"];
        Pin = Request.Form["Pin"];
        Mobile = Request.Form["mobile"];
        IsNRI = Request.Form["IsNRI"];
        stateId = Request.Form["stateId"];
        categoryId = Request.Form["categoryId"];
        categoryname = Request.Form["CategoryName"];
        FilePath = Request.Form["FilePath"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dob) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(add1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(add2) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(area) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Pin) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mobile) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsNRI) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryname) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath))
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                bool IsNrI = false;
                if (IsNRI.Equals("True"))
                {
                    IsNrI = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsNrI = false;
                }
                ADD myAdd = new ADD();
                myAdd.Name = name;
                myAdd.Dob = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                myAdd.Add1 = add1;
                myAdd.Add2 = add2;
                myAdd.City = city;
                myAdd.Area = area;
                myAdd.State = state;
                myAdd.Pin = Pin;
                myAdd.Mobile = Mobile;
                myAdd.EmailID = emailID;
                myAdd.IsNRI = IsNrI;
                myAdd.StateId = int.Parse(stateId);
                myAdd.CategoryID = int.Parse(categoryId);
                myAdd.CategoryName = categoryname;
                db.ADDs.InsertOnSubmit(myAdd);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                int newId = myAdd.TabId;
                if (newId > 0)
                {
                    pnlGrid.Visible = true;
                    pnlEntry.Visible = false;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    Literal2.Text = "Record Inserted Successfully!";
                    UpdatePanel1.Update();
                }
            }
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/" + Request.Files["files"].FileName));
        }
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    }
```

here i can't receive file from web client. what can i do?

*************Updated****************

```
wc.UploadFile(DirectCast(New Uri("http://localhost:29478/AddressBook/UploadFiles"), Uri), "POST", "D:\SHALIN\HOW TO INSTALL WEBSITE TO IIS.docx")


The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

Second Trick :

```
 Dim wc As WebClient
            wc = New WebClient
            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
            wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2")
            wc.UploadFileAsync(DirectCast(New Uri("http://localhost:29478/AddressBook/UploadFiles"), Uri), "POST", "D:\SHALIN\HOW TO INSTALL WEBSITE TO IIS.docx")
            wc.Dispose()
```

How ever this code works fine but not getting file at aspx page

```
        foreach (string f in Request.Files.AllKeys)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/" + file.FileName));
        }
```

Comment: You can send file at webservices

Comment: What a mess...please try to clean it up.
Why would you want to post the file to a webform from code? Please describe your use case, what your are trying to do might be done but there are other (more convenient) ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simplified code piece which shows how to send a file to a webpage:

C# for sending

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

string fileName = "path to file 2 send";
string uriString = "url asp page 2 receive";

byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(uriString,fileName);
```

ASP.NET page

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net"%>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web"%>

<Script language="C#" runat=server>
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs("c:\\inetpub\\test\\UploadedFiles\\" + file.FileName);
    }   
}

</Script>
<html>
<body>
<p> Upload complete.  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Src: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I use this code but still i'm getting this error see update.

Comment: Can't see any update. Have you updated your question yet?

Comment: @GajjarShalin I tested my answer and it works. You appear to have some other kind of error and that is a completely different question, so please add that as a new question, with that new code you use, and we can have a look at that.

Comment: @GajjarShalin I also see one thing which appears wrong. You can't have `"POST"` in this line: `wc.UploadFile(DirectCast(New Uri("http://localhost:29478/AddressBook/UploadFiles"), Uri), "POST", "D:\SHALIN\HOW TO INSTALL WEBSITE TO IIS.docx")`. It should only be the url and the file.

Comment: I understand ur logic but i have small problem while it can't sends files to another web page with onyl string like file how ever i can't post files with postReq.ContentType = "multipart/form-data" and another thing is postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". How ever i can't sent file with second content type. If i use first then i can't send data's to another page.  please help me...

Comment: @GajjarShalin Check these 2 posts about sending form data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793755/how-to-fill-forms-and-submit-with-webclient-in-c-sharp ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp